# Single query or multiple queries on mongodb with mongoskin???

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin, nosql

this is on mongodb

```
{cod_com:'WWWOAN',
     cod_prod[{prod:'proda',info:'hola mundo'},{prod:'pacda',info:'hola mundo'},{prod:'prcdb',info:'hola mundo'}]
}
{cod_com:'WWWOA2',
     cod_prod[{prod:'prdda',info:'hola mundo'},{ccod:'prcda',info:'hola mundo'}]
}
{cod_com:'WWWOA1',
     cod_prod[{prod:'prcda',info:'hola mundo'},{aaad:'prcda',info:'hola mundo'}]
}
```

i have to get the info inside the cod_prod variables... so im working with two steps

first i query the owner of the cod_prod

```
db.collection.findOne({cod_com:'WWWOA1'});
```

if exists, i query the cod_prod that i need

```
db.collection.findOne({'cod_prod.prod':'prcda'});
```

so basically im querying two times, first is to the the owner of the product, and the second the info of the product that im searching...

the question is, there is any way to search the prod directly???

i cant use this...

```
db.collection.findOne({'cod_prod.prod':'prcda'});
```

because differents owners has same product... so first i get the owner and second i get the product....

anybody has a better aproach?? or a different way to get the info??? tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you query like this:

```
db.collection.findOne({'cod_com':'WWOA1', 'cod_prod.prod':'prcda'});
```

you should get the result you want.

Comment: if i want to get the cod_com wich contains 'cod_prod.prod':'prcda', how can i get that info... the owner info

Comment: the query didnt give me the array... gives me all the document i need only the info... not the entire document

Comment: By default query always returns full document.  You can use $elemMatch projection operator to get just first matching array element.

Comment: Yeah thats what im looking for